# Retrieve data from firebase using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Good Morning,
Hope you all doing well,

I want to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database and display it in profile user using Firebase Realtime Database and authentication database, and there's the code to understand.

Thanks in advance

Sign up:

```js
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                Users users = new Users(name, email, password, phonenumber);

                                databaseReference.setValue(users);//.push()
                                
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, Home.class));
                                finish();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Register failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Profile xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profile">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle2"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/back"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/linear"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Mon Profile "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nom"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="email"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tphonenumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="numéro "
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tpassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mot de passe"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/editProfileButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="Modifier Profile"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do this code for Profile.java, but it does not work:

```java
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView back;
    AppCompatButton mEditButton;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;\
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_profile);

        back = findViewById(R.id.back);

        // In your onCreate method:
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUser.getUid());

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get user data from the dataSnapshot
                String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String password = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                String phoneNumber = dataSnapshot.child("phonenumber").getValue(String.class);

                // Display user data in profile
                TextView emailTextView = findViewById(R.id.temail);
                emailTextView.setText(email);

                TextView nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.tname);
                nameTextView.setText(name);

                TextView passwordTextView = findViewById(R.id.tpassword);
                passwordTextView.setText(password);

                TextView phoneNumberTextView = findViewById(R.id.tphonenumber);
                phoneNumberTextView.setText(phoneNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The realtime data

[image]

The auth data

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: There is **way** too much code here for us to effectively help with, and not enough information on what's going wrong. Somebody may of course happen to catch what's going wrong, but chances drastically go up if you increase the focus and information. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and follow those instruction to update your question to be more concise and actionable.

Comment: @RoshanKumar No , just the app don't display anything and in logcat all attributes are null

Comment: Have you tried to read the data only once with using `get()` ?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 1):

> No, just the app doesn't display anything and in logcat all attributes are null.

This is happening because you're trying to read user data from a location that doesn't exist. When you create the following reference and attach a listener to it:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()                              
                                          .child("Users")
                                          .child(currentUser.getUid());
//
```

It means that you want to read data under a node, that is the UID of the user that was provided in the authentication process. Such a UID contains 28 characters and looks like this:

[image]

On the other hand, in your database, there are no such nodes:

[image]

See? Those nodes are created using the [DatabaseReference#push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method. To solve this issue, when you create the user data in the database, remove the call to push(), because each time you call it, it generates a new random ID. And instead, use the UID of the user. In code, it will be as simple as:

```
mDatabase.setValue(userObj);
```

Comment: i remove the push like you said, but still the data don't display in profile

Comment: i add in the code SignUp for you can see the way i add an user in database

Comment: It's not correct, it should be `databaseReference.child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(users);`. Give it a try and tell me if it works. Besides that, be aware that you're using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, so if you create a user, the second time you run the code you won't be able to create the user again.

Comment: Do you have an idea about edit Profile ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "edit profile". Did you try the solution in my answer? Does it work?

Comment: 'Edit profile' means the user will be able to edit her information 'name, email, password and phone number'

Comment: You're very welcome, Myriam. Good to hear that it worked :)

Comment: Regarding the "Edit profile" question, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey Myriam. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?